# How to use 2 third party .net libraries when their unmanaged dependencies conflict?

Tags: .net, windows, deployment, dll

Say I have a .net assembly A.dll that uses third party .net assembly B.dll and third party .net assembly C.dll.

It turns out that internally B.dll uses unmanaged assembly D.dll (version 1)
and C.dll uses unmanaged assembly D.dll (version 2).

B and C come from different vendors and are only tested with their correct version of D.dll.

How can I deploy A such that B and C will work correctly?

Edit:

I think there are three distinct problems:

1) How to externally control the paths B and C use for looking for D .

2) How to externally control the paths D uses for its own dependencies.

3) How to ensure the process directs function calls correctly.

My research suggests that without compile time control of all modules this may be impossible...

Answer (score 1):

i would try to configure several bin folders by means of "probing" configuration section.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin\B;bin\C"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

then i would put B.dll and its unmanaged dependencies into bin\B folder, and C.dll and its unmanaged dependencies in bin\C folder.

Comment: From my understanding this would redirect for finding B and C however this would not automatically chain for the unmanaged searching for D.

Comment: @morechilli: as far as i understand B and C should look for its dependencies next to itself, so each (B and C) should find corresponding versions of D

Comment: thanks for the help - do you have a link to anything that describes this behaviour - I haven't found any suggestion that this is the case.

Comment: @morechilli: no, i do not have specific links. i just think that 1) if assembly imports DLL via managed wrapper (Interop.*.dll) then the assembly loads the wrapper using standard assembly resolution logic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3(v=VS.71).aspx) and the wrapper SHOULD know where the DLL is located; 2) if assembly imports DLL via DllImport attribute then CLR (PInvoke) uses another DLL resolution procedure. I tend to believe PInvoke tries to find DLL next to assembly. But it's just my guess. Have you tried that?